# How can i store iOS remote notification when app in state background or killed, and without tap the notification?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I want to save all the notifications from server.Is that only way is to request server to get all messages?

Comment: please elaborate your question

Answer (score 0):

You may use silent notification feature which lets your app do simple operations (e.g. purchase sync or file sync) without bothering the user or having the user open the app.